# "Syntax Error" is displayed due to change in curly braces

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, ejs

I'm trying to run this code using node.js
This code shows a "Syntax Error" when I run the code below.

```
<% friends.forEach(function(friend) %>
<% { %> 
    <li>I have a friend: <strong><%= friend %></strong></li>
<% }); %>
```

But it seems to work fine if I change the opening curly brace to this syntax.

```
<% friends.forEach(function(friend){ %>
    <li>I have a friend: <strong><%= friend %></strong></li>
<% }); %>
```

Can someone please explain why this happens? I am using an ejs template engine.

Comment: What template engine are you using? lodash?

Comment: What's the idea behind putting the curly bracer in a new line if it works on the second example?

Comment: I'm used to the first code syntax and I would like to know the reason why

Comment: I'm using ejs template engine